# Linux WiFi menu (not settings) shows up in top-center alltough it should be in the top-right corner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface

[image: https://prnt.sc/uYzJpVtPGAYF]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the WiFi menu is at the top-center of the display, but it should be in top-right corner.

I don't know what I did. Is there a  way to get it back to its place?

Comment: That is just the menu. The WiFi Icon is top right where it normally lives.

Comment: @John And how am I supposed to get it back to top-right corner?

Comment: Menus can move around - that is, not fixed. Your main icon is correctly located

Comment: This is likely related to some theme you installed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I didn't install anything. I just installed Raspberry Pi OS without installing anything special to it.